# What if we use this kind of region of rejection?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

I'm wondering how do we decide the "shape" of region of rejection in a hypothesis testing problem. Let's take a two-tailed z-test as an example. What if we choose the weird-looking region of rejection on the left instead of the more widely-used one on the right?

[image]
[image]

While I intuitively believe choosing the classic one is a better idea, the significance level of both tests are 0.05, so what makes one superior to the other?

Answer (score 2):

> what makes one superior to the other?

The [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)) of the left one is much lower than that of the right. To quote the Wikipedia entry:

> The power of a binary hypothesis test is the probability that the test correctly rejects the null hypothesis (H0) when a specific alternative hypothesis (H1) is true.

Talking about significance without power doesn't have much meaning. You could simply ignore the observations, generate a random number between 0 and 1, and reject if less than something predetermined, for example.

Comment: This answer looks convincing but I just cannot wrap my mind around this: is *power* related to the *power function*? Also since the power function is continuous, we can say $\alpha + \beta = 1$ at the “juncture” of H0 and H1. Thus, increasing power means reducing $\beta$, which would also increase $\alpha$, and that doesn’t seem good to me..,